# Is the 'this' pointer only hidden in C++ or in java too?

Tags: java, c++, pointers, this, hidden

I've been doing a large amount of studying lately, and I was working on C++, and the topic of the hidden pointer (`this`).

It is one of the most complex topics I have seen so far. I remember `this` from Java, and I don't remember anything about it being hidden in Java. I do remember that you have to explicitly use it in Java, but apparently it's automatic in C++. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden" and "explicitly use it"? In most respects, `this` works identically in C++ vs. Java.

Comment: Hidden in C# as well.

Comment: @dlf In C++, when you create a class method, you do not have to write this->mVar = var  or something along those lines because it is implicit, while in Java you have to write this.mVar = var

Comment: You don't have to explicitly use `this` in Java unless you're trying to resolve name collision.

Comment: You can't use `this` to chain constructors or access outer classes in C++. Those are the only differences that occur to me (aside from the dot/arrow thing).

Comment: In Stroustrup's book it says
An ordinary member function declaration specifies three logically distinct things
[1] The function can access the private part of the class declaration, and 
[2] The function is in the scope of the class, and 
[3] the function must be invoked on an object ( has a **this** pointer)
However, in a textbook I am reading they give an example of a class ( Person ) and they say that it is equivalent to the exact same thing plus this ->. And then they say 
In the latter case, the **this** pointer is used explicitly, and in the former case it is used implicitly.

Comment: This is where I got my question. Is it also used implicitly in Java.

Comment: I assume that by "hidden", the texts mean a "hidden parameter" -- not a visible parameter in the parameter list.  And in that regard C++, Java, and Objective-C are the same -- "this" ("self" for Objective-C) is "hidden" in the sense that it's passed in the parameter list ahead of the first formal parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hidden? It's not hidden. What does that even mean?

> I do remember that you have to explicitly use it in Java

Only in some circumstances. A variable called `name` could be known inside the class and also be the name of a parameter in a method. Example:

```
class Test {
    String name;

    public void test(String name) {
        name = name; // What happens?
    }
}
```

Both times `name` is mentioned it refers to the parameter. The class field is unchanged. You have to tell the compiler that you want `this.name` if you want the class field.

In other circumstances, when there are no collision in names, the `this.` part is implicit. Example:

```
class Test {
    String tutorName;

    public void test(String name) {
        tutorName = name; // What happens?
    }
}
```

The class field is changed even though you didn't use the `this` keyword.

Comment: Hidden in C++ not in Java, I know that it is explicit in Java.

Comment: @MutantCoder then you know wrong.

Comment: In C++, the ' this ' pointer is used "under the hood" to tell the class method which object it is referring to. I wanted to know if that worked in Java as well. and its implicit

Comment: I don't know what *exactly* you're trying to say, but C++ and Java behave the same here. You don't have to write `this`, but if you do, you *explicitly* tell the compiler that you refer to a member. If you don't, it *might* refer to a member *unless there is no other local variable hiding the member*. In both C++ and Java.